# How to do this recursivly: ls -lrt -d -1 $PWD/{*,.*}

Tags: linux, ls

In another post located here:
[List file using ls command in Linux with full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27340307/list-file-using-ls-command-in-linux-with-full-path/27340401#27340401)

The answer to the question was given as this:

```
ls -lrt -d -1 $PWD/{*,.*}
```

But this does not work recursively even if I add -R to it.
Can someone please provide me with the correct syntax to have the same results but recursively? 
Thank you

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `find` command to go finding the files.  You're looking for something like:

```
$ find . | xargs ls -lt -d -1
```